# Make the uikit slideshow height to auto adjust per content height

Tags: html, css, uikit

I've tried using the following code. It works fine with this problem. But after using this code, when I swiping between slides they got shrink to a side before fit into the screen.
I cannot set a default height because these slides should be responsive.
Please help to fix this code or suggest a new way to adjust the height per content height.

css

```
ul.ul_tools-construction {
    display: table-row;
}

ul.ul_tools-construction li {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```
<div uk-slideshow="autoplay: true; animation: fade">
    <div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle" tabindex="-1">
        <ul class="uk-slideshow-items ul_tools-construction">
            <li> </li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for coming up with any way to solve this problem.